# flutter timer only updating seconds widget

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I followed a Flutter tutorial that builds a stopwatch.

The app builds and runs, however I can't get it to update the hours(HRS) and minutes(MIN) part of the widget.  It only updates the seconds(SEC).

I've tried moving pieces of the code around and debugging, but I only end up breaking the whole thing so it doesn't run at all.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Here is the app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new TimerAppState();
  }
}

class TimerAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);

  int secondsPassed = 0;
  bool isActive = false;

  Timer timer;

  void handleTick() {
    if(isActive) {
      setState(() {
        secondsPassed = secondsPassed + 1;
      });
    }
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  if (timer == null)
    timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t)
    {
      handleTick();
    });

    int seconds = secondsPassed * 60;
    int minutes = secondsPassed ~/ 60;
    int hours =secondsPassed ~/ (60 * 60);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Timer'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                CustomTextContainer(label: 'HRS', value: hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                CustomTextContainer(label: 'MIN', value: minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                CustomTextContainer(label: 'SEC', value: seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                ],
              ),

              Container(
                margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child:RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(isActive ? 'STOP' : 'START'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isActive = !isActive;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextContainer extends StatelessWidget {

  CustomTextContainer({this.label, this.value});

  final String label;
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$value',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 34,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              '$label',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to get this to work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add all updated values inside `setState` method  not just seconds

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new TimerAppState();
  }
}

class TimerAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  static const duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);

  int secondsPassed = 0;
  bool isActive = false;

  Timer timer;
  int seconds, minutes, hours;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (timer == null)
      timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t) {
        handleTick();
      });
  }

  void handleTick() {
    if (isActive) {
      setState(() {
        secondsPassed = secondsPassed + 1;
        seconds = secondsPassed * 60;
        minutes = secondsPassed ~/ 60;
        hours = secondsPassed ~/ (60 * 60);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Flutter Timer'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomTextContainer(
                        label: 'HRS', value: hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                    CustomTextContainer(
                        label: 'MIN',
                        value: minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                    CustomTextContainer(
                        label: 'SEC',
                        value: seconds.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(isActive ? 'STOP' : 'START'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isActive = !isActive;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class CustomTextContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextContainer({this.label, this.value});

  final String label;
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '$value',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 34, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            '$label',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white70,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please with this example how do i get incremental time like call duration timer...thnx. My problem mainly is how to return seconds to zero once secondsPassed reaches 59.

Comment: seconds = t.tick - (hours * (60 * 60)) - (minutes * 60);

Answer (score 1):

Use som modulos %

```dart
int seconds = secondsPassed % 60;
int minutes = secondsPassed ~/ 60 % 60;
int hours = secondsPassed ~/ (60 * 60) % 24;
```